# How do anxiety disorders affect our brains on a neuro level?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, anxiety

I was specifically wondering about

a) The effect on plasticity. Given that stress has been implicated to reduce plasticity, I assumed anxiety disorders would have a similar effect but the only paper I could find suggested excessive neuroplasiticity (in the amygdala) in patients with anxiety disorders.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4872422/

b) Whether it leads to atrophy in the pfc. The effect on cognition seems pretty clear cut but the evidence on whether anxiety disorders cause atrophy in the pfc also seem mixed, which to me is odd because how could it there be a decrease long term in cognitive functions.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm concerned that this might not work as a question because it deals with two distinct issues each requiring separate treatments to do them justice. Might I suggest that you narrow this to one question, and ask the other in a separate thread. You're bound to get more focused and complete answers that way I'd have thought.